# Meaning of the quote "As Above So Below; As Within So Without"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, quotations

I was reading *The Secret* when I came across the above quote and couldn't understand it in spite of googling

Comment: This is a very formalized/formulaic utterance; it is not something a person would ever say in casual conversation or newspaper prose, for example; the register is ritual/prayer/incantation.  You might hear something like this in a story about witches and warlocks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what *the secret* is, but the first part is probably a reference to an idea in [The Lord's Prayer](http://www.lords-prayer-words.com/lord_traditional_king_james.html)

> ...in earth, As it is in heaven...

Above is Heaven, below is Earth, and so it means

> It is the same on Earth as it is in Heaven

The second is probably intended as a similar idea: within and without in this context mean inside and outside. Within is still widely used, but without is quite old fashioned.

Comment: **without** is old-fashioned, but **within** still gets used fairly often in AmE, but not with *buildings* so much as with precincts, confines, areas, regions, etc.

Comment: @TRomano: agreed. London had a city wall, built in by the Romans in 200AD. This church (built 1200AD) was just outside one of the gates in the wall. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Botolph-without-Bishopsgate